# If $X$ has a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$ that is, $P[X=1]=p=1- P[X=0]$ , $E[Y|X=0]=1$, and $E[Y|X=1]=2$, what is $E[Y]$?

Tags: probability

If $X$ has a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$

that is, $P[X=1]=p=1- P[X=0]$ , $E[Y|X=0]=1$, and $E[Y|X=1]=2$, what is $E[Y]$?

I tried this:

$E[Y]= 0(P[Y=0]) + 1 (P[Y=1]) = (P[Y=1]) $

given that $E[Y|X=1]=2$ then $E[Y|X=1] = (P[Y=1 , X=1]) / (P[X=1]) = (P[Y=1 , X=1]) / p ,  $ finally 
$(P[Y=1 , X=1])= 2p$ analogically

given that $E[Y|X=0]=1$ then $E[Y|X=0] = (P[Y=1 , X=0]) / (P[X=0]) = (P[Y=1 , X=0]) / 1-p ,  $ finally 
$(P[Y=1 , X=0])= 1-p$ the conclusion is $E[Y] = (P[Y=1]) = (2p) + (1-p) = 1+p $

Am I right?? thanks four yours help :) have a nice day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. This is an example of the [Law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) which is $E(Y) = E(E(Y|X))$. In your case, you know $E(Y|X)$, it is 1 when X=0 and 2 when X=1. So we need to find the expected value of a random variable that takes the value 1 with probability $1-p$ and 2 with probability $p$. That is, as you wrote yourself above, $1\cdot (1-p) + 2 \cdot p$ or $1 - p + 2p = 1+p$.

Comment: Thanks for your time and your help :D

Comment: My pleasure :).